# Skipping MSBuild target

Tags: msbuild

Is there a way to use MSBuild syntax to skip a specific target?

I have a file consisting of a lot of properties (lines containing `/property:X=Y`) that I want to pass on to a recursively called instance of MSBuild, but this file also contains a `/target:X line`, that I do not want to have any effect.

I don't have the option to modify the file.

Comment: We need more info, could you paste the target calling MSBuild recursively please?

Comment: <Exec
  Command="msbuild35.cmd $(MSBuildProjectFullPath) /t:Build $(MSBuildArgs) TheFile"
/>

TheFile contains the /target: line that I want to ignore.

Comment: And msbuild32.cmd just sets a bunch of environment variables and then runs "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\MSBuild.exe %*"

Comment: What is a TheFile? A filepath? An item? A property?

Comment: TheFile is a file containing a lot of "/property:X=Y" lines, that I want to pass on to the recursively invoked MSBuild file.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I suppose you are able to edit .proj file. You can manage MSBuild targets executing by the `Condition`. Your target, which you want to exclude, could contain something like this:

```
<Target 
    Name="SomeTarget" 
    Condition="'$(SomeProperty)'=='true'" 
    DependsOnTargets="SomeAnotherTarget"/>
```

`SomeProperty` can be passed in the calling:

```
MSBuild.exe build.proj /p:SomeProperty=false
```